# HapiJS and Socket IO not emit

Tags: socket.io, hapi

I'm trying to setup socket.io with hapi. I've setup a barebones repo here: https://github.com/imcodingideas/socketio-hapi-example but this is the gist of it. On the `server.js` I am listening for a connection

```
  io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit({ msg: 'welcome' })
  })
```

and on the client I'm sending a connection

```
socket.on('msg', data => {
  console.log(data)
  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' })
})
```

I'm not getting any cors errors or nothing so it's able to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does work and it doesn't matter where you put the `server.start()`.

The problem is your client side code. The event `socket.on('connection')` does not exist for the socket.io client. The event is called `connect`.

[IO - Event: ‘connect’ Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99)

The following code snippet should work.

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:8081');

socket.on('connect', data => {
    console.log('connected');
});

socket.on('msg', data => {
    console.log(data);
});

setTimeout(() => {
    socket.emit('another event', 'another events data')
}, 2000)
```

server:

```
const init = async () => {
  const io = SocketIO.listen(server.listener)

  io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit('msg', 'welcome')

    socket.on('another event', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  })

  await server.start()
  console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`)
}
```

Comment: That DID fix my issue with the client side. What about the server side?

Comment: I've edited a small example emitting an event and receive it on serverside with a small timeout. The serverside implementation is one way which also hapijs docu shows and its working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Do not start the server before you initialize the Socket Listener.

```js
'use strict'

const Hapi = require('hapi')
const SocketIO = require('socket.io')

const server = Hapi.server({
  port: 8081,
  host: 'localhost'
})

const init = async () => {
  // await server.start() // not here

  const io = SocketIO.listen(server.listener)

  io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit('msg', 'welcome')
  })

  await server.start() // but  start it here.
  console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`)
}

init()
```

---

#### Pro tip

**You can use [Firecamp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firecamp-a-campsite-for-d/eajaahbjpnhghjcdaclbkeamlkepinbl) to test socket events and listeners visually**

[image]

Comment: this seems like it should have worked but it did not. I've updated my repo: 

https://github.com/imcodingideas/socketio-hapi-example